# Panels & Float Column

Tags: panels

Do any of you have experience with Panels & Floating column? I am creating a template site where I will have side bars on the left and right side. But since this is a template site, sometimes I will not have content in the left and or right and would like floating columns so the content adjust properly.

Comment: Can you explain what `floating columns` means?